# gnu.io.NoSuchPortException is occuring while executing the program

Tags: java, rxtx

> Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1    native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
>   gnu.io.NoSuchPortException    at
>   gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:269)

The above exception is coming while executing the below code, where `portName` is `"COM1"`:

```
CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
```

Please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: Clearly your port name not exists.

Answer (score 0):

From the RXTX `NoSuchPortException` source: "The requested Port does not exist"

This also seems to happen if RXTX is not correctly installed. See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274179/nosuchportexception-using-rxtx-java-library-on-windows)